# Proving $\operatorname{Tr}((AB)^m)=\operatorname{Tr}((BA)^m)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

We know that $\operatorname{Tr}(AB)=\operatorname{Tr} (BA)$
How can we prove that $\operatorname{Tr}((AB)^m)=\operatorname{Tr}((BA)^m)$ ?
I tried to use induction but it seemed that in the last step for $m+1$ I had to use the result and that was wrong.
Can anyone explain a nicer way?
Any hint can help.
Thank you

Comment: $(AB)^m = AB(AB)^{m-1} = A(BA)^{m-1}B$. Now, inside a trace, you can move $A$ to the right and be done.

Comment: Oh My God! Thank you! It was really trivial 

Answer (score 1):

Use $\operatorname{Tr}UV=\operatorname{Tr}VU$ with $U:=A,\,V:=(BA)^{m-1}B$.

Comment: Thank you. I get it :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let's try for the case $Tr[(AB)^2]=Tr[(BA)^2]$.

$$Tr[(AB)^2]=Tr[(AB)(AB)]=Tr[ABAB]=Tr[A(BAB)]=$$
$$Tr[(BAB)A]=Tr[BABA]=Tr[(BA)^2]$$

Did you get it? Did you understand how to approach the general case?

Comment: Yes, yes thank you!!